# Cache in Storage array

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, cache, iscsi

Hi I just started working in a Storage Lab.

I am new to Storage Area Networks, I did lot of searching on Internet about this.

I have two doubts :

How can we know whether a Storage array has a cache or not. (with iSCSI protocol)

How to know if any new device is added to storage array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we know whether a Storage array has a cache or not. (with
>   iSCSI protocol)

It has to be documented by the administrators, there is no way to see this.

> How to know if any new device is added to storage array.

E.g. with the help of something like [iSNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISNS), but this will dependent on your local configuration. Again, documentation is important as well.

Comment: Hmmm, I knew so thats why asked whether there is any way to find out or not, ( what if your s/w has to be independent of the storage array and has to work in all cases ).

Comment: Nice Gravitar :)